# Which header to include in order to call `cout << std::vector<_Ty>`?

Tags: visual-c++, vector, header-files, cout

I'm trying to follow the *Option Details* sectionof  the [tutorial for the Boost Program Options library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2607297) and I'm getting the following error:

```
error C2679: "binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
of type 'const std::vector<_Ty>'" (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

My code is below. I'm guessing I need to include a header, but I don't know which one.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int options_description(int ac, char* av[])
{
    int opt;
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("optimization", po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10), 
            "optimization level")
        ("include-path,I", po::value< vector<string> >(), "include path")
        ("input-file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "input file")
    ;

    po::positional_options_description p;
    p.add("input-file", -1);

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).
        options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("include-path"))
    {
        cout << "Include paths are: " 
             << vm["include-path"].as< vector<string> >() << "\n"; // Error
    }

    if (vm.count("input-file"))
    {
        cout << "Input files are: " 
             << vm["input-file"].as< vector<string> >() << "\n"; // Error
    }

    cout << "Optimization level is " << opt << "\n";   

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return options_description(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to compile this code?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build the project. I believe the options are as follows: `cl /c /ZI /nologo- /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt main.cpp`

Comment: Are you sure Visual Studio knows where to look for the boost libraries (see [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide) for details)

Comment: I've already confirmed Boost is working. The problem isn't with boost, but with the sample code. I believe the cause is that the `cout` class doesn't have a implementation of the `<<` operator that accepts a `vector` object.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer to my question (I'd prefer a standard library feature that did this), but I found similar question with an answer that provides a class that implements the `<<` operator on the `ostream` class that accepts `vector` object:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " ")); 
    return os;
}
```

I added this to my code and it now compiles. Too bad this wasn't mentioned in the tutorial.

Source: [Vector string with boost library C++ gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413194/vector-string-with-boost-library-c-gives-error)